# jquery need get unix date format from DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: jquery, unix-timestamp

My script put into the input field date with DD-MM-YYYY format.
Now i need to change this date into unix (e.g. 1450220400).

Is any way to do that with with simple jQuery code?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using moment.js

Comment: And someone downvoted you probably because this question is scattered all over SO.

Comment: propably? i think this person don't find post with this what i iwas needed... always easlier downvote than bring something constructive.. I will not call this person by his name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Date("12-12-2012".split("-").reverse().join("-")).getTime()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for that. JavaScript's date handling is very basic, but more than enough for the job.

```
var dateString = '26-11-2015';
var dateObj = new Date(dateString.substr(6, 4), dateString.substr(3, 2) - 1, dateString.substr(0, 2));
var unixTime = dateObj.getTime();
console.log(dateObj); // Wed Nov 26 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100
```

To explain the `-1`: Months in JavaScript have a range from 0 (january) to 11 (december).

Answer (score 0):

take a look at moment.js.

first parse your date string like [this](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)
and then take a look at this: unix [timestamp](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/)

[EDIT] moment.js handles although the problems with "month count starts at zero"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a Date object in JavaScript and then calling the getTime method.

```
new Date(YYYY, MM, DD).getTime()
```

For example:

```
> new Date(1999, 10, 20).getTime()
943084800000
```

The output is in milliseconds so you can divide by 1000 to get seconds.

```
> new Date(1999, 10, 20).getTime() / 1000
943084800
```